# How to draw lines by its degree wrt to the x-axis?

Tags: r, graphics

I want to draw a line 45 degrees with respect to the x-axis in R base graphics. How to calculate the slope of the line so that it is drawn 45 degrees with respect to the x-axis?

EDIT: The people answered the question can not get it right.

Let me rephase it. Please draw a 45 degree line on the following plot.

```
# You should not assume a particular device size.
# for example, you may use pdf(width=17, height=11)
# or some arbitrary width and height
# if you use a fixed slope,
# then the angle will not be constant when you change the device size
plot(1:10, (1:10)*10)
```

The 45 degree means what you see on the screen. slope of 1 is certainly not of 45 degree unless you scale your screen to a particular value.

Comment: You certainly learnt at school that a slope of **b** means that when you move horizontally from one unit then you have to move vertically from **b** units. Then by elementary trigonometry you can see that the slope is the tangent of the angle.

Comment: I am not sure about the dpi. But if increasing x  by 1 means 1in in the output device, but increasing y by 10 means 1in in the output device, then the 45 degree line will be a line with slope=10/1.

Comment: That is exactly what the purpose of this questions for on how to find out the correct slope.

Answer (score 0):

**Update II:**

With a given point (x,y) and a given angle of 45° we could do it this way. Main point is to get the correct intercept:

```
# formula
# y=slope*x+intercept 

x =5
y =3
slope <- tan(45)
intercept = (slope*x - y)*-1


plot.new()
plot(-5:5, -5:5, type = "n")# setting up coord. system
abline(h=0, v=0)
points(5,3, pch = 22, cex=2, col="green", bg="red", lwd=2)
abline(a=intercept, b=slope, col="red")
#a, b : single values specifying the intercept and the slope of the line
```

[image]
[image]

**Update I:**
I am sorry but I don't know if it is clear for you that **each line through the positive x axis with a degree of 45 has the slope 1!?**

**See here:**

General approach:
slope of line through (point x,y) with an angle of 45°:
**slope = tan(alpha)**
Inclination of alpha is the angle of line with positive x-axis.

**For your example:**
slope = tan(45°) = 1
Take any point of x,y for example (x, y) = (5,3):

y - y0 = slope(x-x0)

**hence:**
y - 3 = 1 (x-5)
y = x-2

y = the intercept = 3
Now you have x, the intercept and the slope and you could plot:

```
plot.new()
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
abline(a=y, b=1)

#a, b : single values specifying the intercept and the slope of the line
```

You get:
[image]

Maybe you want a line through the x axis then you have to adapt the intercept:

```
plot.new()
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
abline(a=-3, b=1)
#a, b : single values specifying the intercept and the slope of the line
```

You get:
[image]

**First answer:**

You could modify the degree of `45°` as you desire: Note angles are in radians for the `tan` function!

```
plot.new()
plot(x=0, y=0, xlim=c(1, 8), ylim=c(1, 8), pch=15, cex=3)
abline(a=0, b=tan(45*pi/180))
```

[image]

Comment: You don't get the point of the question. What if the plot's xy is not of the same range?

Comment: That is quite possible. Maybe they could consider my update and share their thoughts. Many thanks!

Comment: Again, your first two plots are not of 45 degree. They look like around 60 degrees.

Comment: Last try. Please see my update!

Comment: @user1424739 This is 45 degrees, but you see something because of the aspect ratio. Set **asp=1**.

Comment: The 45 degree means what you see. You should delete the irrelevant answers. You should not assume a particular aspect ratio as I have not assumed one in my original question.

Comment: There is a dive into the guts needed to both achieve what you want to do and understand what you're seeing at any given iteration. [Figure Layout - Melissa Clarkson](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2012/12/making-prettier-network-graphs-with-sna-and-igraph/) and `?plot.window`, where you set world coordinates for graphics windows, taken together, explain, why the answers above aren't irrelevant, are where you'd want to start a plot strategy, rather than just a call to `plot()`.

Comment: The answer should exactly answer my question. I don't need anything tangentially relevant.